# How to slice a Pandas Dataframe based on datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, slice

This has been bothering me for ages now:

Given a simple pandas DataFrame

```
>>> df

Timestamp     Col1
2008-08-01    0.001373
2008-09-01    0.040192
2008-10-01    0.027794
2008-11-01    0.012590
2008-12-01    0.026394
2009-01-01    0.008564
2009-02-01    0.007714
2009-03-01   -0.019727
2009-04-01    0.008888
2009-05-01    0.039801
2009-06-01    0.010042
2009-07-01    0.020971
2009-08-01    0.011926
2009-09-01    0.024998
2009-10-01    0.005213
2009-11-01    0.016804
2009-12-01    0.020724
2010-01-01    0.006322
2010-02-01    0.008971
2010-03-01    0.003911
2010-04-01    0.013928
2010-05-01    0.004640
2010-06-01    0.000744
2010-07-01    0.004697
2010-08-01    0.002553
2010-09-01    0.002770
2010-10-01    0.002834
2010-11-01    0.002157
2010-12-01    0.001034
```

How do I separate it so that a new DataFrame equals the entries in df for the dates between `2009-05-01` and `2010-03-01`

```
>>> df2

Timestamp     Col1
2009-05-01    0.039801
2009-06-01    0.010042
2009-07-01    0.020971
2009-08-01    0.011926
2009-09-01    0.024998
2009-10-01    0.005213
2009-11-01    0.016804
2009-12-01    0.020724
2010-01-01    0.006322
2010-02-01    0.008971
2010-03-01    0.003911
```

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#indexing

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you have set the "Timestamp" column as the index , then you can simply use

```
df['2009-05-01' :'2010-03-01']
```

Comment: additionally, if you only need one date, you can do `df.loc['2009-05-01']` :)

Comment: Additionally. If you have also time in your index, you can use it like this `df.loc['2009-05-01 00:00:00':'2009-03-01 23:00:00']`.

Comment: This works if and only if you have ordered indexes with no other non-related columns in between your interval columns

Comment: And how to do this if the index Date is in a Descending order without re-sorting the dataframe?  Say a slice from the top of the dataframe to some date?  `df.loc[:my_date]`  returns the tails rather the the head.  Thank you

Answer (score 11):

IIUC, a simple slicing?

```
from datetime import datetime
df2 = df[(df.Timestamp >= datetime(2009, 05, 01)) &
         (df.Timestamp <= datetime(2010, 03, 01))]
```

Comment: Note there is no need to use `datetime`: `df[(df.Timestamp >= '2009-05-01') & (df.Timestamp <= '2010-03-01')]` will do

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
df2 = df.set_index('Timestamp')['2009-05-01' :'2010-03-01']
print(df2)
```