# What is the easiest way in Pandas to a filter a dataframe by non-contiguous months?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

For example, I have data from Jan 2019 to July 2020. I want to filter data for: 2019 : (Jan, May, Aug, Sep, Dec and 2020: (Jan, May, June).

What is a simple way of doing this?

Edit: It is a datetime column

Comment: Depends a lot on how the data is stored. Is it a DatatimeIndex? A multiindex with Datetime? A string column? A Datetime column? Could you share a snippet of your data?
Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868647/how-to-slice-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-datetime-index/49868730?

Comment: Hello, please take time to read : how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. This post might help in doing so: [How to make good reproducible examples in pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do that with [Pandas: Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) using synthetic data:

```
dates = pd.date_range("2019-01-01", "2020-07-31", freq="23d")
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": dates, "a": range(len(dates))})
mask = (df.date.dt.month.isin([1, 5, 6, 7, 12]) & (df.date.dt.year == 2019)) |  \
       (df.date.dt.month.isin([1, 5, 6]) & (df.date.dt.year == 2020))
df[mask]
```

The output is:

```
         date   a
0  2019-01-01   0
1  2019-01-24   1
6  2019-05-19   6
7  2019-06-11   7
8  2019-07-04   8
9  2019-07-27   9
15 2019-12-12  15
16 2020-01-04  16
17 2020-01-27  17
22 2020-05-21  22
23 2020-06-13  23
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

There is are methods to get the month and year, which you can then form a tuple, or just store as 2 columns. After that it is the same as the normal filtering that you do in pandas. Perhaps apply the following function logic onto the column where you stored the month year tuple

```
def monthmask(month_year):
    list = [...]  # List of tuples containing your desired months and years

    if month_year in list:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```