# how to make a slice by week and year in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a table

| Year | Week | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 47 | 56 |
| 2021 | 48 | 5 |
| 2021 | 49 | 4 |
| 2021 | 50 | 6 |
| 2021 | 51 | 7 |
| 2021 | 52 | 10 |
| 2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021 | 2 | 3 |

I want to get all data from 2021 year 49 week. However if I make the following slice:

```
table[(table.Year >= 2021) & (table.Week >= 49)]
```

I get the data for every week that >= 49 for every year starting 2021. How to conclude into the slice weeks 1-48 year 2022 without creating new column? I mean how to get all data from the table starting from year 2021 week 49 (2021: week 49-52, 2022: week 1-52, 2023: week 1-52 etc.)

Comment: Do you need `table[table.Year == 2022) & (table.Year < 49)]` ? What means `conclude into the slice`  ?

Comment: one option is to create a MultiIndex and then you can slice with that

Comment: I mean how to get all data from the table starting from year 2021 week 49 (2021: week 49-52, 2022: week 1-52, 2023: week 1-52 etc.)

Comment: Use datetime format in pandas, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868647/how-to-slice-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-datetime-index/49868730)

Answer (score 4):

You're missing an OR. IIUC, you want data beyond Week 49 of 2021. In logical expression that can be written as the year is greater than 2021 OR the year is 2021, but the week is greater than 49:

```
out = table[((table.Year == 2021) & (table.Week >= 49)) | (table.Year > 2021)]
```

Output:

```
   Year  Week  Sales
2  2021    49      4
3  2021    50      6
4  2021    51      7
5  2021    52     10
6  2022     1      2
```

Comment: @jezrael OP wants " all data from the table starting from year 2021 week 49 (2021: week 49-52, 2022: week 1-52, 2023: week 1-52 etc.)". This produces that