# How to take out only the data of No. 26

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import pivot_table

df = pd.read_excel('test-2022-07-27 15：06：20.xlsx')

table = pivot_table(df,values='Num', index=['Date','counties'], columns=['server'], aggfunc='count',fill_value=0)

table.to_excel('after.xlsx')
```

This is the result of running

[image]

How to take out only the data of No. 26

Comment: What is No. 26? And when you say take out, do you mean remove, or replace with other values?

Comment: I mean to take out the data of 2022-7-26, which is similar to the filtering in Excel PivotTable

Comment: Hi, slice before saving to Excel. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49868647/11246056

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to slice a Pandas Dataframe based on datetime index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868647/how-to-slice-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-datetime-index)